# Analyse large text file using php and preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match, file-get-contents

We have a large log file which captures the api requests and responses for a data management system. We are trying to identify and count which api.methods are being used by using the following:

```
$filename = (external file name on log server >1Gb)

$filecontents = file_get_contents($filename);

preg_match_all("/=> api.(.*)/", $filecontents, $apimethods);

$countmethods=array_count_values($apimethods[1]);
```

$countmethods provides us with the array which we can then display on our page.

We know this method is not ideal but are struggling to find better ways to do this.

This is on an internal server so we've increase the memory limit - but we know that's not very efficient.

```
ini_set ('memory_limit', filesize ($a) + 10000000000);
```

Comment: Implement some form of log rotation, instead of adding more and more data to one massive file …?

Comment: Do you mean to escape the dot after `api`?  How about halving the output array of matches with `/=> api\.\K.*/` ? Then just access `[0]` in the matches. (This isn't a viable solution, just a thought, which is why I didn't post as an answer.)

Comment: Why don't you import all that data into a database?

Comment: The log data is in json format, but because of the way the logs work, it has formatted in a way where we can't convert it - example below:

`[16-01-2019 04:27:48]:     Array
(
    [0] => api.search_results
    [1] => Array`

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents()` reads the whole file into memory in one shot, this is where almost all of your usage is coming from. To make it more efficient, you could use `fgets()` in a loop, read one line at a time, and scan with `preg_match()` instead of `preg_match_all()`. This would likely be slower, but would use almost no memory in comparison.

However, neither of these methods will be as fast or efficient as simply using command-line [grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html). You could run a cron to grep the log and dump the matches to a file, then use PHP to read/parse that file for your display.